# Jsoup Remove Everything before a H2 tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup, extract

I have my HTML source that I get from a website using `Jsoup.connect()` method. Following is an piece of code from that HTML source (link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community)

```
.....
<p>When you set dependencies in your VSIX manifest, you must specify Component IDs 
   only. Use the tables on this page to determine our minimum component dependencies. 
   In some scenarios, this might mean that you specify only one component from a workload. 
   In other scenarios, it might mean that you specify multiple components from a single 
   workload or multiple components from multiple workloads. For more information, see 
   the 
<a href="../extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017" data-linktype="relative-path">How to: Migrate Extensibility Projects to Visual Studio 2017</a> page.</p>
.....
<h2 id="visual-studio-core-editor-included-with-visual-studio-community-2017">Visual Studio core editor (included with Visual Studio Community 2017)</h2>
.....
<h2 id="see-also">See also</h2>
.....
```

What I want to do using `jsoup` is that, I would like to remove every single Html piece before `<h2 id="visual-studio-core-editor-included-with-visual-studio-community-2017">Visual Studio core editor (included with Visual Studio Community 2017)</h2>`

,and everything after (including) `<h2 id="see-also">See also</h2>`

I have a solution like this, but this pretty much didnt work for me:

```
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(Constants.URL).get();
        }
        catch (IOException iex) {
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }
        document = Parser.parse(document.toString().replaceAll(".*?<a href=\"workload-and-component-ids\" data-linktype=\"relative-path\">Visual Studio 2017 Workload and Component IDs</a> page.</p>", "") , Constants.URL);
        document = Parser.parse(document.toString().replaceAll("<h2 id=\"see-also\">See also</h2>?.*", "") , Constants.URL);
        return null;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more about this ? If you wanted to remove why don't you select and remove particular class or tag ? or else you can choose only particular tag u want.

Comment: The html page I receive has a complicated structure. It has a lot of tags crunched between other tags. You can check for yourself. The page src is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community.

What I am trying to do is to scrape in the HTML source between "Visual Studio core editor (included with Visual Studio Community 2017)" [1] and "Unaffiliated components" [2] . 

But I am not able to get how to replace anything before [1] and anything after the table of [2]. Please check the site too

Comment: Moreover I wanted to do this using JSOUP, and I am parsing HTML from a website, so it is not a constant file (like you are saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way could be: get the whole html of the page as a string, make a substring of the part you need and parse that substring once again with jsoup.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community").get();
        String html = doc.html().substring(doc.html().indexOf("visual-studio-core-editor-included-with-visual-studio-community-2017")-8, 
                                           doc.html().indexOf("unaffiliated-components")-8);
        Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(html);
        System.out.println(doc2);
```

Comment: Thanks sir. With a little modification to your code, I could get what I wanted.   You've really helped me solve a big problem

Answer (score 1):

I'll just make a small change to @eritrean s answer above. There is small modification to be made for me to get the required output.

```
document = Jsoup.parse(document.html().substring(document.html().indexOf("visual-studio-core-editor-included-with-visual-studio-community-2017")-26,
                document.html().indexOf("see-also")-8));
System.out.println(document);
```